# docker-compose-maven-plugin Failed to execute goal up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, maven-plugin

I use the following plugin:

```
         <plugin>
              <groupId>com.dkanejs.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>docker-compose-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.0</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>up</id>
                  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>up</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <composeFile>${project.basedir}/docker-compose.yml</composeFile>
                    <detachedMode>true</detachedMode>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                <configuration>
                  <build>true</build>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
         </plugin>
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
 services:
   webapp:
     container_name: test_db
     build: src/
     depends_on:
        - psql
   psql:
      container_name: docker_db
      build: database/
      expose:
       - 5432
      ports:
       - 5432:5432
```

Dockerfile_tk:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8-alpine

ENV PATH_TOMCAT_USERS /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ENV PATH_MANAGER /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/
ADD config/tomcat-users.xml  /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD config/context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
ADD test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Dockerfile_db:

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_USER andrej
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD password
ENV POSTGRES_DB test_db
```

But I receive: `Failed to execute goal up`

When I run only  Dockerfile_tk  or Dockerfile_db separetly, docker works successfuly. Problem in docker-compose.

When I run it from terminal, using "docker-compose up" it returns: 
Building psql
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `build: src/` and `build: database/` tells docker-compose to look in the src/ and database/ directories for a file called Dockerfile, but you've named the files Dockerfile_tk. Rename the "Dockerfile_tk" files to "Dockerfile".

Comment: Thank you! Its working now!